# Rewriterule to forward to another domain and i get 404 not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all the traffic from siteone.com to sitetwo.com using a rewriterule on Apache's .htaccess. The goal is to show the sitetwo.com content, while keeping siteone.com on the browser's address bar, but for some reason I get a 404 error.

Here's my .htaccess on siteone.com:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.sitetwo.com [P]
```

The error is as simple as:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at www.siteone.com Port 80
```

Do you have any clue on what could cause the issue?

Comment: You're using `[P]` flag. Does your mod_proxy is enabled? Also you need to use 1st capturing group to end of sitetwo.com. Like `http://www.sitetwo.com/$1 [P]`

Comment: You're right! It seems that mod_proxy is not enabled. I will ask our web provider to activate it. Thanks for now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the proxy module that needed to be activated. Thanks Rahil Wazir for your help!

The module can be activated by uncommenting the correspondent row in the httpd.conf Apache file. I also needed to add a few sub-modules (proxy_connect, proxy_http).